# How to plot bars next to each other?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have a histogram with 4 different objects on each bin, that now are stacked on top of each other. Instead, I need to plot the different objects side by side within the same histogram bin (similar to the top left plot in https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/statistics/histogram_multihist.html):

```
bins=np.logspace(np.log10(0.01),np.log10(20), 11)

plt.hist(a[nosfr]/1e+11, bins, color='red', fill=True, linewidth=2, density=True, histtype='bar', edgecolor='k')

plt.hist(a[highsfr]/1e+11, bins, color='orange', fill=True, linewidth=2, density=True, histtype='bar', edgecolor='k')

plt.hist(b[mynosfr]/1e+11, bins, color='blue', edgecolor='k', fill=True, linewidth=2, density=True, alpha=0.7, histtype='bar')

plt.hist(b[myhighsfr]/1e+11, bins, color='cyan', edgecolor='k', fill=True, linewidth=2, density=True, alpha=0.7, histtype='bar')

plt.xscale('log')
plt.xlim(2e-2, 2e+1)
```

`[nosfr]`, `[highsfr]` etc. draw objects with different criteria within the same sample (`a` and `b`). All the examples I've looked at are slightly different from what I need, and I can't find the right way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Call plot method from your data frame with kind parameter set to bar.

```
x = np.random.random((10, 4))
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

This is the result:
[image: Bar plot]

Comment: If I use this method with your 'x' = my 'bins', and columns=[a[nosfr], a[highsfr] ...] I get 'ValueError: all arrays must be same length'.

Comment: It was just to make the example, you should use your own data.